# How are class_weights being applied in sklearn logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am interested in how sklearn apply the class weight we supply. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) doesn't state explicitly where and how the class weights are applied. Nor does reading the source code helps (seems like sklearn.svm.liblinear is used for the optimization, and I can't read the source codes since it is a .pyd file...)

But I guess it works on the cost function: when class weights are specified, the cost of the respective class will be multiplied by the class weight. For example if I have 2 observations each from class 0 (weight=0.5) and class 1 (weight=1) respectively, then the cost function would be:

> Cost = 0.5*log(...X_0,y_0...) + 1*log(...X_1,y_1...) + penalization

Does anyone know whether this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the following lines in the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L622-L625):

```
le = LabelEncoder()
if isinstance(class_weight, dict) or multi_class == 'multinomial':
    class_weight_ = compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
    sample_weight *= class_weight_[le.fit_transform(y)]
```

[Here is the source code for the `compute_class_weight()` function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py#L9-L70):

```
...
else:
    # user-defined dictionary
    weight = np.ones(classes.shape[0], dtype=np.float64, order='C')
    if not isinstance(class_weight, dict):
        raise ValueError("class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None,"
                         " got: %r" % class_weight)
    for c in class_weight:
        i = np.searchsorted(classes, c)
        if i >= len(classes) or classes[i] != c:
            raise ValueError("Class label {} not present.".format(c))
        else:
            weight[i] = class_weight[c]
...
```

In the snippet above `class_weight` are applied to `sample_weight`, which is used in a few internal function like [_logistic_loss_and_grad](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L116-L117), [_logistic_loss](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L161-L162), etc.:

```
# Logistic loss is the negative of the log of the logistic function.
out = -np.sum(sample_weight * log_logistic(yz)) + .5 * alpha * np.dot(w, w)
# NOTE: --->  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```